# avoid PHP case sensitivity on replace function

Tags: php

I have the following code use to show the thumbnail of an image, the thumbnail is create with _small placed at the end of the file name. Its a simple replace function:

```
<?php
if ($row_rsAdminMenu['image1']) {
    $src = $row_rsAdminMenu['image1'];
    $src = str_replace('.JPG', '_small.JPG', $src);
} else {
    $src = '../../images/NoPic.jpg';
}
echo '<img src="' . htmlspecialchars($src, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . '" />'; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not very clear in the question, but I think that you want to be able to alter the filename as follows:

```
image.JPG -> image_small.JPG
image.jpg -> image_small.jpg
```

This can be done using [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) using back references, for example:

```
php > echo preg_replace('/(^.*)(\.jpg)$/i', '\1_small\2', 'image.jpg');
image_small.jpg
php > echo preg_replace('/(^.*)(\.jpg)$/i', '\1_small\2', 'image.JPG');
image_small.JPG
php > echo preg_replace('/(^.*)(\.jpg)$/i', '\1_small\2', 'image.jPg');
image_small.jPg
```

This works by inserting `"_small"` between the 2 matched groups.

In the context of your code:

```
<?php
if ($row_rsAdminMenu['image1']) {
    $src = $row_rsAdminMenu['image1'];
    $src = preg_replace('/(^.*)(\.jpg)$/i', '\1_small\2', $src);
} else {
    $src = '../../images/NoPic.jpg';
}
echo '<img src="' . htmlspecialchars($src, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . '" />'; ?>
```

With a minor modification it can also work for other file extensions if desired:

```
php > echo preg_replace('/(^.*)(\.(jpg|gif|png|jpeg))$/i', '\1_small\2', 'image.PNG');
image_small.PNG
```

Comment: I'm sorry was original question was not clear, stackover flow froze when I submitted original question, I refreshed but it missed the rest of the question off.
Thank you for your help works like a charm, brilliant

Answer (score 1):

You can use [str_ireplace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) for case insensitive replace.

```
 $src = str_ireplace('.JPG', '_small.JPG', $src);
```

Comment: This does work but if the original image had .jpg it creates a thumbnail with _small.jpg so the above fails because PHP is case sensitive on the _small.JPG. This there a way to show thumbnail whether its _small.JPG or _small_.jpg?

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
echo preg_replace('/.jpg/i', '', '_small.JPG');
```

Or if want to remove multiple extensions -

```
echo preg_replace('/.(jpg|gif|png)/i', '', '_small.JPG  _small.GIF');
```